# javascript : property and method access in an object

Tags: javascript-objects

Consider this variable:

var myString = "kodjo play football";

alert(myString.length); // display myString length
alert(myString.toUpperCase()); // display characters as upper case

Here my concern:
We don't define this property and this method in our object myString. But we access them in it. Can someone give me more explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define some variable like var myVar = "text"; js detects what type of this variable, and after you can use all methods of current object.
So, if you create new variable myVarString = "text"; - type of this variable is String, but when you create variable myVarNotString = 5; this will an integer type, and in this case you can't use methods like string, so you can't use myVarNotString.length. But you can cast them to string and check length: var newString = myVarNotString.toString().length